# How to one-hot-encode from a pandas column containing a list?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I would like to break down a pandas column consisting of a list of elements into as many columns as there are unique elements i.e. `one-hot-encode` them (with value `1` representing a given element existing in a row and `0` in the case of absence).

For example, taking dataframe **df**

```
Col1   Col2         Col3
 C      33     [Apple, Orange, Banana]
 A      2.5    [Apple, Grape]
 B      42     [Banana]
```

I would like to convert this to:

**df**

```
Col1   Col2   Apple   Orange   Banana   Grape
 C      33     1        1        1       0
 A      2.5    1        0        0       1
 B      42     0        0        1       0
```

How can I use pandas/sklearn to achieve this?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

We can also use [sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html):

Often we want to use **sparse** DataFrame for the real world data in order to save a lot of RAM.

## Sparse solution (for Pandas v0.25.0+)

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer(sparse_output=True)

df = df.join(
            pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix(
                mlb.fit_transform(df.pop('Col3')),
                index=df.index,
                columns=mlb.classes_))
```

result:

```
In [38]: df
Out[38]:
  Col1  Col2  Apple  Banana  Grape  Orange
0    C  33.0      1       1      0       1
1    A   2.5      1       0      1       0
2    B  42.0      0       1      0       0

In [39]: df.dtypes
Out[39]:
Col1                object
Col2               float64
Apple     Sparse[int32, 0]
Banana    Sparse[int32, 0]
Grape     Sparse[int32, 0]
Orange    Sparse[int32, 0]
dtype: object

In [40]: df.memory_usage()
Out[40]:
Index     128
Col1       24
Col2       24
Apple      16    #  <--- NOTE!
Banana     16    #  <--- NOTE!
Grape       8    #  <--- NOTE!
Orange      8    #  <--- NOTE!
dtype: int64
```

---

## Dense solution

```
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df.pop('Col3')),
                          columns=mlb.classes_,
                          index=df.index))
```

Result:

```
In [77]: df
Out[77]:
  Col1  Col2  Apple  Banana  Grape  Orange
0    C  33.0      1       1      0       1
1    A   2.5      1       0      1       0
2    B  42.0      0       1      0       0
```

---

Comment: You might find timings interesting.

Comment: This seems to be extremely memory consuming. My 160 GiB machine is running out of memory with 1000000 rows and 30000 columns.

Comment: @DawidLaszuk, try to make use of `MultiLabelBinarizer(sparse_output=True)`

Comment: @MaxU Yes, my bad, the issue is not with MLB but with pandas itself (or more likely with my usage of it). For testing might need to find a way to discard entries outside 100 most common values.

Comment: @DawidLaszuk, i think it would make sense to open a new question, provide there a small reproducible sample data set and your desired data set...

Comment: I got this error using the sparse solution - 
AttributeError: type object 'DataFrame' has no attribute 'sparse'

Comment: @codenewbie, what is your Pandas version? It should be working for any Pandas version starting from version 0.25.0 ...

Answer (score 83):

**Option 1**
*Short Answer*
`pir_slow`

```
df.drop('Col3', 1).join(df.Col3.str.join('|').str.get_dummies())

  Col1  Col2  Apple  Banana  Grape  Orange
0    C  33.0      1       1      0       1
1    A   2.5      1       0      1       0
2    B  42.0      0       1      0       0
```

---

**Option 2**
*Fast Answer*
`pir_fast`

```
v = df.Col3.values
l = [len(x) for x in v.tolist()]
f, u = pd.factorize(np.concatenate(v))
n, m = len(v), u.size
i = np.arange(n).repeat(l)

dummies = pd.DataFrame(
    np.bincount(i * m + f, minlength=n * m).reshape(n, m),
    df.index, u
)

df.drop('Col3', 1).join(dummies)

  Col1  Col2  Apple  Orange  Banana  Grape
0    C  33.0      1       1       1      0
1    A   2.5      1       0       0      1
2    B  42.0      0       0       1      0
```

---

**Option 3**
`pir_alt1`

```
df.drop('Col3', 1).join(
    pd.get_dummies(
        pd.DataFrame(df.Col3.tolist(), df.index).stack()
    ).astype(int).groupby(level=0).sum()
)

  Col1  Col2  Apple  Orange  Banana  Grape
0    C  33.0      1       1       1      0
1    A   2.5      1       0       0      1
2    B  42.0      0       0       1      0
```

---

**Timing Results**
*Code Below*

[image]

---

```
def maxu(df):
    mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
    d = pd.DataFrame(
        mlb.fit_transform(df.Col3.values)
        , df.index, mlb.classes_
    )
    return df.drop('Col3', 1).join(d)


def bos(df):
    return df.drop('Col3', 1).assign(**pd.get_dummies(df.Col3.apply(lambda x:pd.Series(x)).stack().reset_index(level=1,drop=True)).sum(level=0))

def psi(df):
    return pd.concat([
        df.drop("Col3", 1),
        df.Col3.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(1, x)).fillna(0)
    ], axis=1)

def alex(df):
    return df[['Col1', 'Col2']].assign(**{fruit: [1 if fruit in cell else 0 for cell in df.Col3] 
                                       for fruit in set(fruit for fruits in df.Col3 
                                                        for fruit in fruits)})

def pir_slow(df):
    return df.drop('Col3', 1).join(df.Col3.str.join('|').str.get_dummies())

def pir_alt1(df):
    return df.drop('Col3', 1).join(pd.get_dummies(pd.DataFrame(df.Col3.tolist()).stack()).astype(int).sum(level=0))

def pir_fast(df):
    v = df.Col3.values
    l = [len(x) for x in v.tolist()]
    f, u = pd.factorize(np.concatenate(v))
    n, m = len(v), u.size
    i = np.arange(n).repeat(l)

    dummies = pd.DataFrame(
        np.bincount(i * m + f, minlength=n * m).reshape(n, m),
        df.index, u
    )

    return df.drop('Col3', 1).join(dummies)

results = pd.DataFrame(
    index=(1, 3, 10, 30, 100, 300, 1000, 3000),
    columns='maxu bos psi alex pir_slow pir_fast pir_alt1'.split()
)

for i in results.index:
    d = pd.concat([df] * i, ignore_index=True)
    for j in results.columns:
        stmt = '{}(d)'.format(j)
        setp = 'from __main__ import d, {}'.format(j)
        results.set_value(i, j, timeit(stmt, setp, number=10))
```

Comment: That's brilliant, really! PS I just used my last voting shot for today ;-)

Comment: That's fast!  Like your timings chart.  I assume the *x-axis* is the number of rows in the dataframe?

Comment: @Alexander thx, x-axis is number of multiples of `df`... was lazy with the labeling.  So 1000 is `pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)`

Comment: Just saw that in your code.  Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @Alexander I'm a stickler for matching output to get apples to apples.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150125/discussion-between-alexander-and-pirsquared).

Comment: Why is that dummies works by separating each list element if you pass str.join('|'), but not if you pass str.join('-') (it will consider the whole string together)?

Comment: @Sapiens It would work with `str.join('-')`.  It is just that the default separator for `get_dummies` is the `"|"`.  So you'd change it to `df.drop('Col3', 1).join(df.Col3.str.join('-').str.get_dummies(sep='-'))`

Comment: I used `"|"` because I knew it was the default.

Comment: Ok. I just didn't knew enough about get_dummies() settings for this to be clear to me. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 28):

**Method 1** using [`explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html#//apple_ref/Method/pandas.DataFrame.explode) (new in version 0.25.0.) and [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html#//apple_ref/Function/pandas.crosstab):

```
s = df['Col3'].explode()
df[['Col1', 'Col2']].join(pd.crosstab(s.index, s))
```

or in Python 3.7+:

```
df[['Col1', 'Col2']].join(pd.crosstab((s:=df['Col3'].explode()).index, s))
```

**Method 2** using [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
from itertools import chain

lst = sorted(set(chain.from_iterable(df['Col3'])))
s = pd.Series(lst, index=lst)
df.join(df.pop('Col3').apply(lambda x: s.isin(x)).astype(int))
```

Output:

```
  Col1  Col2  Apple  Banana  Grape  Orange
0    C  33.0      1       1      0       1
1    A   2.5      1       0      1       0
2    B  42.0      0       1      0       0
```

Comment: This answer should be way more popular ... Thanks for this neat solution!

Comment: some of my row have empty list, and after applying above code, the new columns get NaN value. is there any way we can set Nan to 0?

Comment: This was the cleanest answer, by far, BUT I could not unstack the df. It's not terribly big.

Comment: @harshpoddar You can use `fillna(0)`.

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful solution! `df1` seems to be a `pd.Series`, not `pd.DataFrame`. Just wanted to leave it hear in case the name `df1` confuses anyone.

Answer (score 8):

Use `get_dummies`:

```
df_out = df.assign(**pd.get_dummies(df.Col3.apply(lambda x:pd.Series(x)).stack().reset_index(level=1,drop=True)).sum(level=0))
```

Output:

```
  Col1  Col2                     Col3  Apple  Banana  Grape  Orange
0    C  33.0  [Apple, Orange, Banana]      1       1      0       1
1    A   2.5           [Apple, Grape]      1       0      1       0
2    B  42.0                 [Banana]      0       1      0       0
```

Cleanup column:

```
df_out.drop('Col3',axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  Col1  Col2  Apple  Banana  Grape  Orange
0    C  33.0      1       1      0       1
1    A   2.5      1       0      1       0
2    B  42.0      0       1      0       0
```

Comment: +1 for use of `**` with `get_dummies`, but this might be slow for large dataframes because of `.stack()` and method chaining.

Comment: @BradSolomon Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure this quite works... Try it after: `df = pd.concat([df, df])`

Answer (score 6):

You can loop through `Col3` with `apply` and convert each element into a Series with the list as the index which become the header in the result data frame:

```
pd.concat([
        df.drop("Col3", 1),
        df.Col3.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(1, x)).fillna(0)
    ], axis=1)

#Col1   Col2    Apple   Banana  Grape   Orange
#0  C   33.0      1.0      1.0    0.0     1.0
#1  A    2.5      1.0      0.0    1.0     0.0
#2  B   42.0      0.0      1.0    0.0     0.0
```

Answer (score 5):

You can get all unique fruits in `Col3` using set comprehension as follows:

```
set(fruit for fruits in df.Col3 for fruit in fruits)
```

Using a dictionary comprehension, you can then go through each unique fruit and see if it is in the column.

```
>>> df[['Col1', 'Col2']].assign(**{fruit: [1 if fruit in cell else 0 for cell in df.Col3] 
                                   for fruit in set(fruit for fruits in df.Col3 
                                                    for fruit in fruits)})
  Col1  Col2  Apple  Banana  Grape  Orange
0    C  33.0      1       1      0       1
1    A   2.5      1       0      1       0
2    B  42.0      0       1      0       0
```

**Timings**

```
dfs = pd.concat([df] * 1000)  # Use 3,000 rows in the dataframe.

# Solution 1 by @Alexander (me)
%%timeit -n 1000 
dfs[['Col1', 'Col2']].assign(**{fruit: [1 if fruit in cell else 0 for cell in dfs.Col3] 
                                for fruit in set(fruit for fruits in dfs.Col3 for fruit in fruits)})
# 10 loops, best of 3: 4.57 ms per loop

# Solution 2 by @Psidom
%%timeit -n 1000
pd.concat([
        dfs.drop("Col3", 1),
        dfs.Col3.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(1, x)).fillna(0)
    ], axis=1)
# 10 loops, best of 3: 748 ms per loop

# Solution 3 by @MaxU
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()

%%timeit -n 10 
dfs.join(pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(dfs.Col3),
                          columns=mlb.classes_,
                          index=dfs.index))
# 10 loops, best of 3: 283 ms per loop

# Solution 4 by @ScottBoston
%%timeit -n 10
df_out = dfs.assign(**pd.get_dummies(dfs.Col3.apply(lambda x:pd.Series(x)).stack().reset_index(level=1,drop=True)).sum(level=0))
# 10 loops, best of 3: 512 ms per loop

But...
>>> print(df_out.head())
  Col1  Col2                     Col3  Apple  Banana  Grape  Orange
0    C  33.0  [Apple, Orange, Banana]   1000    1000      0    1000
1    A   2.5           [Apple, Grape]   1000       0   1000       0
2    B  42.0                 [Banana]      0    1000      0       0
0    C  33.0  [Apple, Orange, Banana]   1000    1000      0    1000
1    A   2.5           [Apple, Grape]   1000       0   1000       0
```