# Turn a Pandas Python list into Boolean columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas python dataframe that has one column that is just a list of tags, somewhat like is shown below.

```
Index | User_Details | Tags
------|--------------|-------
0     | A            |[tag_a, tag_b]
1     | B            |-
2     | C            |[tag_a]
....  | ...          |....
```

This list column has an unknown, varying number of tags and users can have none, one or many of them. They are separated by commas. What I am trying to do is turn it into a boolean table like that shown below:

```
Index | User_Details | tag_a | tag_a
------|--------------|-------|-------
0     | A            |1      |1
1     | B            |0      |0
2     | C            |1      |0
....  | ...          |....   |...
```

I found some things on here that did this when the tags were limited and all known. Usually there were like only 3 tags, but I'm looking at up to 30ish.

Any ideas?

Thanks

NOTE: This is different to [How to one-hot-encode from a pandas column containing a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45312377/how-to-one-hot-encode-from-a-pandas-column-containing-a-list) as some of my tag rows contain no data. Using any of the methods applied there usually results in a failure along lines of:
TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()

Comment: Can you print `df.head(5).to_dict()` and paste the output here? It is near impossible reproducing your data.

Comment: For the tags section it is: {0: [],
 1: [u'RSVP - Kickoff - XXXX San Diego - 09/20/2017'],
 2: [u'RSVP - Kickoff - XXXX San Diego - 09/20/2017'],
 3: [u'RSVP - Kickoff - XXXX San Diego - 09/20/2017'],
 4: [u'RSVP - Kickoff - XXXX San Diego - 09/20/2017']}

Comment: Your question has already been answered, it is of no consequence anymore.