# How to transpose and transform to "one-hot-encode" style from a pandas column containing a set?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I want to perform a break down to a pandas column similarly to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45312377/how-to-one-hot-encode-from-a-pandas-column-containing-a-list):

I want to transpose and then "one-hot-encode" style. For example, taking dataframe **df**

```
Col1           Col2
 C      {Apple, Orange, Banana}
 A      {Apple, Grape}
 B      {Banana}
```

I would like to convert this and get:

**df**

```
Col1        C   A   B   
Apple       1   1   0
Orange      1   0   0
Banana      1   0   1
Grape       0   1   0
```

How can I use pandas/Sklearn to achieve this?

Comment: You could one-hot encode (as in your linked answer), *then* transpose with `df = df.T`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible answer (assuming Col1 is your index):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
one_hot_encoded = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df['Col2']), columns=mlb.classes_, index=df.index)
one_hot_encoded.T
```

Answer (score -1):

You could transform the multi hot encoding output itself and then create a dataframe.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df['Col2']).T, columns=df.Col1, index= mlb.classes_)
```

output:

```
Col1    C   A   B
Apple   1   1   0
Banana  1   0   1
Grape   0   1   0
Orange  1   0   0
```

Note:  we cannot still call this as one hot encoding. It is multi hot encoding but in transformed form.

[Examples](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#encoding-categorical-features)