# Make cell values as Columns with one-hot encoding

Tags: python, pandas

**Input Df:**

```
ID Values
1  1;6;7
2  1;6;7
3  5;7
4  1;5;9;10;2;3
```

**Expected df**

```
ID 1  2   3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
1  1  0   0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0
2  1  0   0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0 
3  0  0   0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  
4  1  1   1  0  1  0  0  0  1  1
```

**Problem Statement:**

I have a column `Values` which has colon separated values. I now want to make these values as column names and fill those column values with 1 ,0 .

Example: ID 1 has 1;6;7 so ID 1 has `1` in column 1 ,6 and & and rest is `0`

I couldn't find any solution which could achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45312377/how-to-one-hot-encode-from-a-pandas-column-containing-a-list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) with argument `sep=';'`.

The column names will be string, so its necessary to map them to `int` using [`DataFrame.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) then use [`Dataframe.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) and [`numpy.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) for your desired output:

```
(df.Values.str.get_dummies(sep=';')
 .rename(columns=lambda x: int(x))
 .reindex(np.arange(11), axis=1, fill_value=0))
```

[out]

```
  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0
2   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0
4   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! If I also want to get columns like 4 & 8 which have no values i.e. all zeros, can I get that also ?

Comment: @RahulAgarwal apologies, missed that part. updated my answer now