# Perform one-hot encoding on pandas dataframe on multiple column types

Tags: python, pandas, one-hot-encoding, data-processing

So I have a pandas dataframe where certain columns have values of type list and a mix of columns of non-numeric and numeric data.

Example data

```
   dst_address   dst_enforcement   fwd_count ...
1  1.2.3.4       [Any,core]        8
2  3.4.5.6       []                9
3  6.7.8.9       [Any]             10
4  8.10.3.2      [core]            0
```

So far I've been able to find out which columns are non-numeric by these 2 lines of code

```
col_groups = df.columns.to_series().groupby(df.dtypes).groups
non_numeric_cols = col_groups[np.dtype('O')]
```

Of all these non-numeric columns, I need to figure out which ones have list as data type and I want to perform one-hot encoding on all non-numeric columns (including those list type)

EDIT: my expected output for above example would be something like

```
   1.2.3.4 | 3.4.5.6 | 6.7.8.9 | 8.10.3.2 | empty | Any | core | fwd_count ...
1  1         0         0         0          0       1     1      8
2  0         1         0         0          1       0     0      9
3  0         0         1         0          0       1     0      10
4  0         0         0         1          0       0     1      0
```

Comment: wat is the expected output? can you post that in the question? thanks

Comment: One comment, viewing or selecting different dtypes is easier with the built-ins in pandas. `df.dtypes` and `df.select_dtypes()` respectively have saved me a lot of manual work in the past.

Comment: For encoding the list, you can use the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45312377/how-to-one-hot-encode-from-a-pandas-column-containing-a-list), and for the other types you can use `select_dtypes('o')` and `OneHotEncoder`

Comment: @anky_91 I edited my post to include expected output

Comment: are `1.2.3.4` and `3.4.5.6` etc and `Any`, `core` etc stored as strings?

Comment: @Tacratis yes they are

Comment: Right. I see people already answered :) good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use 3 steps as follows:

```
df['dst_enforcement'] = df.dst_enforcement.apply(lambda x: x if x else ['empty'])
dm1 = pd.get_dummies(df[df.columns.difference(['dst_enforcement'])], prefix='', prefix_sep='')
dm2 = df.dst_enforcement.str.join('-').str.get_dummies('-')
pd.concat([dm1, dm2], axis=1)

Out[1221]:
   fwd_count  1.2.3.4  3.4.5.6  6.7.8.9  8.10.3.2  Any  core  empty
1          8        1        0        0         0    1     1      0
2          9        0        1        0         0    0     0      1
3         10        0        0        1         0    1     0      0
4          0        0        0        0         1    0     1      0
```

Comment: This is better than mine. +1

Comment: @Andy other than dst_enforcement, there may be other columns with list as value type. Is there a way to check for this condition or do I have to manually repeat this code block for every list-type column?

Comment: @tlaminator: to find columns having list as value type, just use `applymap` as follows `df.applymap(lambda x: isinstance(x, list)).any()`. Any column contains list will return `True`, others return `False`. Then, just apply logic for columns having list all at once and columns having no list all at others. For detail, I think it deserves a new question. Please ask a new question if you want an expansion of this question

Comment: @Andy: Thanks, this is what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`unnesting`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-to-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe/53218939#53218939) to unnest the lists to seperate roes and call [`pd.get_dummies()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html):

```
df_new=unnesting(df,['dst_enforcement']).combine_first(df)
df_new.dst_enforcement=df_new.dst_enforcement.apply(lambda y: 'empty' if len(y)==0 else y)
m=pd.get_dummies(df_new,prefix='',prefix_sep='').groupby('fwd_count').first().reset_index()
print(m)
```

---

```
   fwd_count  1.2.3.4  3.4.5.6  6.7.8.9  8.10.3.2  Any  core  empty
0        0.0        0        0        0         1    0     1      0
1        8.0        1        0        0         0    1     0      0
2        9.0        0        1        0         0    0     0      1
3       10.0        0        0        1         0    1     0      0
```

Adding the function used for convenience:

```
def unnesting(df, explode):
    idx = df.index.repeat(df[explode[0]].str.len())
    df1 = pd.concat([
             pd.DataFrame({x: np.concatenate(df[x].values)}) for x in explode], axis=1)
    df1.index = idx

    return df1.join(df.drop(explode, 1), how='left')
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a go to:

```
non_numeric_cols = col_groups[np.dtype('O')]

for non in non_numeric_cols:
    print(pd.get_dummies(df[non].apply(pd.Series)))
```

Output:

```
   0_1.2.3.4  0_3.4.5.6  0_6.7.8.9  0_8.10.3.2
   0          1          0          0           0
   1          0          1          0           0
   2          0          0          1           0
   3          0          0          0           1

   0_Any  0_core  1_core
   0      1       0       1
   1      0       0       0
   2      1       0       0
   3      0       1       0
```

When you don't have neither "Any" or "core" the whole row is zeros.

Good luck.

Comment: I think this works for trivial example I gave but my real dataset has > 100 non-numeric columns so when I try to run this my jupyter notebook significantly slows down. Is there a better solution in terms of running time?

Comment: also how would you merge all these new one-hot encoded columns and numeric columns into one dataframe?

Comment: Do you have an index over the columns of interest?

Comment: I have a numpy array of column names? I don't know how to convert that into an array of index