# Convert a column which contains pandas Series to features

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

My data frame is like below:

```
            a
0     [8, 10]
1  [12, 7, 9]
```

As you can see column a contains a list. Number inside that list has meaning in our domain and i want to use them as feature. My expected output is like below:

```
   Tag_7  Tag_8  Tag_9  Tag_10  Tag_12
0      0      1      0       1       0
1      1      0      1       0       1
```

I used some methods that i find from internet they satisfy my expectation but there is a execution time problem with that methods. One of them is like below:

```
pd.get_dummies(df.a.apply(pd.Series).stack().astype(int), prefix='Tag').sum(level=0)
```

I think this method is useful for small datasets. For my case it is not useful. I need help.
Thanks in advance. Have a nice day

Comment: Maybe `pd.Series(['|'.join(map(str, x)) for x in df['a']]).str.get_dummies().add_prefix('Tag_')
`

Answer (score 2):

Give `scikit-learn` a try to see if it helps

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
cols = np.unique(np.concatenate(df.a))
df_final = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df.a), columns=cols).add_prefix('T_')

Out[213]:
   T_7  T_8  T_9  T_10  T_12
0    0    1    0     1     0
1    1    0    1     0     1
```

---

If you need to squeeze every `ms`, use `chain.from_iterable` is faster than `np.concatenate` and use `np.char.add` to `T_` to the column names

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
from itertools import chain

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
cols = np.char.add('T_', np.unique(list(chain.from_iterable(df.a))).astype(str))
df_final = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df.a), columns=cols)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45313942/8839111 this solution is a bit better i think.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of hacking, but you can do like this:

```
df['bitsum'] = df['input'].apply(lambda lst: sum(1 << x for x in lst))
pd.Series(np.array(list(map(lambda x: f'{x:b}', df['bitsum'])))).apply(lambda x: x[::-1]).str.split('')
```

Not sure if it works faster though. If you know how many features you have, you can replace `1 << x` by `1 << (n_max - x)`  and so a) get rid of the string reversal `apply(lambda x: x[::-1])`, b) use `bin` instead of `lambda x: f'{x:b}'` that may seem faster, too.