# How to one-hot-encode from a pandas column composed of a list of space containing strings?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I am trying to convert a single pandas column that is made up of a list of strings (containing spaces) into a one-hot-encoded columns (inputted as a string as a result of reading from excel). I have tried the approaches discussed in the solutions to [How to one-hot-encode from a pandas column containing a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45312377/5858873) but they don't work in this scenario- the individual letters are broken into columns. The other condition is that sometimes the lists can be empty as well.

More concretely, for dataframe **df**

```
Col1   Col2         Col3
 C      4     "['Chocolate cake', 'White wine', 'Peanuts']"
 A      1.7   "[]"
 B      1     "['Chocolate cake', 'Salmon']"
```

I would like to create:

**new_df**

```
Col1   Col2   Chocolate cake White wine Peanuts Salmon
 C      4             1           1        1      0
 A      1.7           0           0        0      0
 B      1             1           0        0      1
```

What is a pythonic way to create this dataframe?

EDIT:

Code for generating the pandas dataframe.

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Col1':['C', 'A', 'B'], 'Col2':[4, 1.7, 1], 'Col3':["['Chocolate cake', 'White wine', 'Peanuts']", \
                                                     "[]",  "['Chocolate cake', 'Salmon']" ]})
```

Comment: Can you code to reproduce the sample data?

Comment: Yes, one second please.

Comment: @Divakar added the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way -

```
import ast
dfC3 = [ast.literal_eval(i) for i in df.Col3]
ids,U = pd.factorize(np.concatenate(dfC3))
df_out = pd.DataFrame([np.isin(U,i) for i in dfC3], columns=U).astype(int)
```

Sample o/p -

```
In [50]: df_out
Out[50]: 
   Chocolate cake  Peanuts  Salmon  White wine
0               1        1       0           1
1               0        0       0           0
2               1        0       1           0
```

If you need it to be concatenated with input df, use `pd.concat([df,df_out],axis=1)`.

---

**More performant with array-assignment**

We can use `array-assignment` to hopefully get more performance, if needed for large datasets (re-using `ids,U` from earlier metrhod) -

```
lens = list(map(len,dfC3))
mask = np.zeros((len(lens),len(U)), dtype=int)
mask[np.repeat(range(len(lens)),lens), ids] = 1
df_out = pd.DataFrame(mask, columns=U)
```

Comment: Thanks Divakar. I made a critical change to the question which prevents this from working for my use case, apologies for that. The input is encoded as a string because of how pd.read_excel works, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

One way using `pd.Series.str.findall`, `join` and `get_dummies`:

```
new_df = df.pop("Col3").str.findall("'(.+?)'").str.join("|").str.get_dummies()
new_df = pd.concat([df, new_df], 1)
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
  Col1  Col2  Chocolate cake  Peanuts  Salmon  White wine
0    C   4.0               1        1       0           1
1    A   1.7               0        0       0           0
2    B   1.0               1        0       1           0
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to convert `Col3` to series of list by using `ast.literal_eval`

```
import ast
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

s = df['Col3'].map(ast.literal_eval)
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()

df_mlb = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(s), columns=mlb.classes_, index=df.index)

Out[29]:
   Chocolate cake  Peanuts  Salmon  White wine
0               1        1       0           1
1               0        0       0           0
2               1        0       1           0
```