# Creating dummy variables from a string column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a pandas df as follows and my goal is to take the `MATCHUP` column and make it several more dummy columns.

```
INDICATOR MATCHUP 
1         [   "APPLE",   "GRAPE" ]
1         [   "APPLE",   "GRAPE" ]
0         [   "GRAPE",   "BANANA" ]
0         [   "PEAR",   "ORANGE" ]
1         [   "ORANGE",   "APPLE" ]
```

Here's a dict of how it looks:

```
{'INDICATOR': [1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
 'MATCHUP': ['[   "APPLE",   "GRAPE" ]',
  '[   "APPLE",   "GRAPE" ]',
  '[   "GRAPE",   "BANANA" ]',
  '[   "PEAR",   "ORANGE" ]',
  '[   "ORANGE",   "APPLE" ]']}
```

So given this df, I would like to create some dummy variables to identify if a value appears in the `MATCHUP`.

Final outcome:

```
INDICATOR MATCHUP                    APPLE GRAPE BANANA PEAR ORANGE
1         [   "APPLE",   "GRAPE" ]   1     1     0      0    0 
1         [   "APPLE",   "GRAPE" ]   1     1     0      0    0
0         [   "GRAPE",   "BANANA" ]  0     1     1      0    0
0         [   "PEAR",   "ORANGE" ]   0     0     0      1    1
1         [   "ORANGE",   "APPLE" ]  1     0     0      0    1
```

Is there a way to accomplish this using pandas? I attempted to accomplish this using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45312377/how-to-one-hot-encode-from-a-pandas-column-containing-a-list) but I think the spacing in the `MATCHUP` column make this method unviable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check `explode` with `str.get_dummies`

```
import ast
df = df.join(df['MATCHUP'].map(ast.literal_eval).explode().str.get_dummies().groupby(level=0).sum())
```

Comment: This unfortunately did not work; It did create the dummy variables, but did not split the MATCHUP. Instead of Apple as Variable1 and Grape as Variable2, this returned [   "APPLE",   "GRAPE" ] as its own Variable

Comment: @JohnThomas check the update , you need first convert the string back to list