# How to create pandas dummies based on column values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I would like to create dummies based on column values...

This is what the df looks like
[image]

I want to create this
[image]

This is so far my approach

```
import pandas as pd
df =pd.read_csv('test.csv')
v =df.Values

v_set=set()
for line in v:
line=line.split(',')
for x in line:
    if x!="":
        v_set.add(x)
    else:
        continue

   for val in v_set:
    df[val]=''
```

By the above code I am able to create columns in my df like this
[image]

How do I go about updating the row values to create dummies?
This is where I am having problems.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas convert a column of list to dummies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29034928/pandas-convert-a-column-of-list-to-dummies)

Comment: If you have a fairly large Series, consider the answer from [Paulo Alves](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41676643/7954504) in the link above

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`pandas.Series.str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html). This will alllow you to split the column directly with a delimiter.

```
df = pd.concat([df.ID, df.Values.str.get_dummies(sep=",")], axis=1)

    ID  1   2   3   4
0   1   1   1   0   0
1   2   0   0   1   1
```

`df.Values.str.get_dummies(sep=",")` will generate

```
    1   2   3   4
0   1   1   0   0
1   0   0   1   1
```

Then, we do a `pd.concat` to glue to df together.

Comment: Thank you this is fantastic. I appreciate it.