# Encode categorical features with multiple categories per example - sklearn

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-extraction, categorical-data

I'm working on a movie dataset which contains *genre* as a feature. The examples in the dataset may belong to multiple genres at the same time. So, they contain a list of genre labels.

The data looks like this-

```
    movieId                                         genres
0        1  [Adventure, Animation, Children, Comedy, Fantasy]
1        2                     [Adventure, Children, Fantasy]
2        3                                  [Comedy, Romance]
3        4                           [Comedy, Drama, Romance]
4        5                                           [Comedy]
```

I want to vectorize this feature. I have tried *LabelEncoder* and *OneHotEncoder*, but they can't seem to handle these lists directly.

I could vectorize this manually, but I have other similar features that contain too many categories. For those I'd prefer some way to use the *FeatureHasher* class directly.

Is there some way to get these encoder classes to work on such a feature? Or is there a better way to represent such a feature that will make encoding easier? I'd gladly welcome any suggestions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29034928/pandas-convert-a-column-of-list-to-dummies) has some impressive answers. On your example data, the last answer by Teoretic (using `sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer`) is 14 times faster than the solution by Paulo Alves (and both are faster than the accepted answer!):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
encoded = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df['genres']), columns=mlb.classes_, index=df.index)
result = pd.concat([df['movieId'], encoded], axis=1)

# Increase max columns to print the entire resulting DataFrame
pd.options.display.max_columns = 50
result
   movieId  Adventure  Animation  Children  Comedy  Drama  Fantasy  Romance
0        1          1          1         1       1      0        1        0
1        2          1          0         1       0      0        1        0
2        3          0          0         0       1      0        0        1
3        4          0          0         0       1      1        0        1
4        5          0          0         0       1      0        0        0
```