# Pandas converting list of variable in dummies in a wider dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dummy-variable

I have imported a json file and I now have a data frame where one column (code) that is a list.

```
index year   gvkey    code
0    1998    15686    ['TAX', 'ENVR', 'HEALTH']
1    2005    15372    ['EDUC', 'TAX', 'HEALTH', 'JUST']
2    2001    27486    ['LAB', 'TAX', 'HEALTH']
3    2008    84967    ['HEALTH','LAB', 'JUST']
```

What I want to get is something as follow:

```
index year   gvkey  TAX  ENVR HEALTH EDUC JUST LAB
0    1998    15686   1     1     1    0    0    0
1    2005    15372   1     0     1    0    1    0
2    2001    27486   1     0     1    0    1    0
3    2008    84967   0     0     1    0    1    1
```

Following [Pandas convert a column of list to dummies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29034928/pandas-convert-a-column-of-list-to-dummies) I tried the following code (where df is my data frame):

```
s = pd.Series(df["code"])
l = pd.get_dummies(s.apply(pd.Series).stack()).sum(level=0)
```

I get the second part of the data right (variables TAX, ENVR, HEALTH, EDUC, JUST and LAB), but loose the first (year and gvkey).

How can I keep the year and gvkey variable?

Comment: I get the error `concat() got multiple values for argument 'axis'`...

Comment: Oops , `pd.concat((df[['year','gvkey']],l),axis=1)` try this, I had a typo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think better solution here is use [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) with [`Series.str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html) and [`Series.str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
df = df.join(df.pop('code').str.join('|').str.get_dummies())
print (df)
       year  gvkey  EDUC  ENVR  HEALTH  JUST  LAB  TAX
index                                                 
0      1998  15686     0     1       1     0    0    1
1      2005  15372     1     0       1     1    0    1
2      2001  27486     0     0       1     0    1    1
3      2008  84967     0     0       1     1    1    0
```

If performance is important use [`MultiLabelBinarizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
df1 = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df.pop('code')),columns=mlb.classes_)

df = df.join(df1)
print (df)
       year  gvkey  EDUC  ENVR  HEALTH  JUST  LAB  TAX
index                                                 
0      1998  15686     0     1       1     0    0    1
1      2005  15372     1     0       1     1    0    1
2      2001  27486     0     0       1     0    1    1
3      2008  84967     0     0       1     1    1    0
```

Your solution is possible, [but slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491274/pandas-split-column-of-lists-into-multiple-columns/35491399#35491399), so better avoid it, also `sum` working only for unique values, for general solution need `max`:

```
df = df.join(pd.get_dummies(df.pop('code').apply(pd.Series).stack()).max(level=0))
print (df)
       year  gvkey  EDUC  ENVR  HEALTH  JUST  LAB  TAX
index                                                 
0      1998  15686     0     1       1     0    0    1
1      2005  15372     1     0       1     1    0    1
2      2001  27486     0     0       1     0    1    1
3      2008  84967     0     0       1     1    1    0
```

Comment: Thanks, this is actually very nice! But for some reason I loose the text and instead of getting EDUC ENVR HEALTH I get A B  C D ...

Comment: @ocut - what solution?

Comment: The first one, sorry.

Comment: @ocut hmmm, it is weird

Comment: Ohh, actually I previously added 'df["code"] = ["; ".join(map(str, l)) for l in df["code"]]' to be later able to export it in stata and that was the problem. Deleting it works just fine, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by below methods:

Method 1: Convert the column to a dataframe and get dummies , then `groupby` on `axis=1` and get max:

```
m = pd.get_dummies(pd.DataFrame(df['code'].tolist())).groupby(lambda x:
    x.split('_')[1],axis=1).max()
final1 = df.drop('code',1).assign(**m)
```

Method 2: Join the list of columns with a `|` and use `series.str.get_dummies`

```
final2 = df.drop('code',1).assign(**df['code'].str.join('|').str.get_dummies())
```

Method 3: Your method with `concat`

```
s = pd.Series(df["code"])
l = pd.get_dummies(s.apply(pd.Series).stack()).max(level=0)
final3 = pd.concat((df.drop('code',1),l),axis=1)
#or final = df.drop('code',1).assign(**l)
```

Comment: `.sum(level=0)` ? why?

Comment: without `pop` it is a bit overomplicated ;)

Comment: @jezrael I like `pop` , but sometimes it doesnot serve well especially when you are in a testing phase since it deletes the column from the dataframe inplace. I agree once you are comfortable using it , it is nice :)

Comment: yop, agree, first is necessary understand it.