# Pandas List of Values to Binary Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of users who purchased various items. I want to breakout that list of values into separate columns and have a binary flag for users who purchased that item.

**Input:**

```
       A           B
0  James  [123, 456]
1   Mary       [123]
2   John  [456, 789]
```

**Expected Output:**

```
       A           B  123  456  789
0  James  [123, 456]    1    1    0
1   Mary       [123]    1    0    0
2   John  [456, 789]    0    1    1
```

**What I've tried** (step by step)

[`df['B'].explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) is my first step:

```
0    123
0    456
1    123
2    456
2    789
```

The using [`get_dummies()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) `pd.get_dummies(df['B'].explode())`:

```
   123  456  789
0    1    0    0
0    0    1    0
1    1    0    0
2    0    1    0
2    0    0    1
```

[Join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) it together on index `df.join(pd.get_dummies(df['B'].explode()))`:

```
       A           B  123  456  789
0  James  [123, 456]    1    0    0
0  James  [123, 456]    0    1    0
1   Mary       [123]    1    0    0
2   John  [456, 789]    0    1    0
2   John  [456, 789]    0    0    1
```

**Problem:**

Now I just need to groupby and combine. However, with millions and millions of rows and customers buying 100s of products, this method of joining/combining is highly inefficient. Is there a more "pandas-friendly" or built in function that does this?

Comment: for performance you can also try using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51420716/9840637) using `MultiLabelBinarizer`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can replace `pd.get_dummies(df['B'].explode()` with `pd.get_dummies(df.B.explode()).sum(level=0)` and join.