# Changing column value according to a comparison rule

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have this DataFrame:

```
classification       text      apple  banana  peach   grape
["apple","grape"]    anytext    NaN     NaN    NaN     NaN
```

How can I check if the column name is in the `classification` column, to get this:

```
classification        text      apple  banana  peach   grape
["apple","grape"]    anytext      1      0       0       1
```

Data:

```
{'classification': [['apple', 'grape']],
 'text': ['anytext'],
 'apple': [nan],
 'banana': [nan],
 'peach': [nan],
 'grape': [nan]}
```

Comment: [MultiLabelBinarizer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51420716/4983450) would be pretty efficient on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could apply a lambda function on "classification" that looks checks if an item in it exists as a column name:

```
cols = ['apple','banana','peach','grape']
df[cols] = df['classification'].apply(lambda x: [1 if col in x else 0 for col in cols]).tolist()
```

Another option is to `explode` + `stack` + `fillna` to get a blank Series where the MultiIndex consists of the index, "classification" and column names of `df`. Then evaluate if any item in "classification" exists as a column name, create a Series, `unstack` + `groupby` + `sum` to build a DataFrame to assign back to `df`:

```
tmp = df.explode('classification')
s = tmp.set_index([tmp.index, tmp['classification']])[cols].fillna(0).stack()
s = pd.Series((s.index.get_level_values(1)==s.index.get_level_values(2)).astype(int), index=s.index)
df[cols] = s.unstack().groupby(level=0).sum()
```

Yet even simpler is to use `explode` + `pd.get_dummies` + `groupby` + `sum` to get the items in "classification" as dummy variables, then update `df` with it using `fillna`:

```
df[cols] = df[cols].fillna(pd.get_dummies(df['classification'].explode()).groupby(level=0).sum()).fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
   classification     text  apple  banana  peach  grape
0  [apple, grape]  anytext      1       0      0      1
```