# Complex One-Hot Encoding Dummies Generation From Lists

Tags: python, pandas, encoding, aggregation-framework

I have a pandas DataFrame like this:

```py
    username    Category
0   user1       ["stackoverflow", "cross_validted"]
1   user2       []
2   user3       ["stackoverflow"]
```

I want to generate the binary dummy columns for each unique user and each unique Category:

```py
    username    stackoverflow   cross_validted
0   user1          1                   1
1   user2          NaN                 NaN
2   user3          1                   0
```

I have tried the pandas explode method to extract all the possible elements from the lists but I was stuck with the duplicated usernames.

Comment: for user 2 it should be `0, 0` not `NaN, NaN`

Comment: I kind of want to get null values on purpose but yea that is a good point

Comment: I think that will answer your question : [Pandas convert a column of list to dummies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29034928/pandas-convert-a-column-of-list-to-dummies)